# How to set a null value in a data extension field using javascript

Tags: javascript, field-update, dataextensions

I am trying to set null in a data extension field using server side java script, but it doesn't work. it is a date time field that goes to "monday, january 1 of 1900 00:00" every time I try do set it as null.

I tried this code

```
  var telequalificacaoDE = DataExtension.Init("envio-telequalificacao");
  telequalificacaoDE.Rows.Update({dt_envio:dt_envio, cadastro_crm:false, dt_resposta: null}, ["cd_pessoa"], [cd_pessoa]);
```

I also tried setting the field "dt_resposta" with other values like "undefined" and "" it does not worked too.

How can I do this?

Please help.

Eros